# setPressed is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I have this in my code and the .setPressed doesn't work:

```
Button btndesligado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
 btndesligado.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //Botão para pôr silêncio!

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        btndesligado.setPressed(true);
        som = false;
        vibrar = false;

    }
 });
```

What is wrong? It doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't work when I open it and click it. It was suposed to be pressed after I press once.

Answer (score 2):

Android is changing the `setPressed` both before and after your `onClickEvent`

so change your code this code

```
btndesligado.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //Botão para pôr silêncio!

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        btndesligado.setPressed(true);
        som = false;
        vibrar = false;

    }
 });
```

to this

```
 btndesligado.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

            // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;


            btndesligado.setPressed(true);    
            som = false;
            vibrar = false;                
            return true;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems nothing wrong with your codes, It's working as you did, It sets the View's internal state to "pressed", or false to reverts the View's internal state from a previously set "pressed" state. And you've put that inside `onClick` of button means it acts only after you press the button,

If you want it pressed or revert then do like this,

```
Button btndesligado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
 btndesligado.setPressed(true);
 btndesligado.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //Botão para pôr silêncio!

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        som = false;
        vibrar = false;

    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
 btndesligado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btndesligado.setPressed(true);
            som = false;
            vibrar = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: now it says to put a final in the modifier btndesligado, but even putting final it doesn't work.

Comment: dont declare it as final... avoid this by declaring button outside onCreate or by creating a seperate function. It works. I have tested.